# Visual Basic Code Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work? (meaning the variable colorChange stays the same throughout function)

Each array (leftRing and rightRing have integer values of numbers ranging from 1 through 4)

```
    Private Sub Solve_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Solve.Click

    countColorChangesInRings(colorChanges)
    RotateLeftRingClockwise()
    countColorChangesInRings(colorChanges)

    End Sub

    Sub countColorChangesInRings(ByRef var As Integer)

    Dim colorChangesLeft As Integer = 0
    Dim colorChangesRight As Integer = 0
    Dim totalChanges As Integer = 0
    ' Count Color Changes in Left Ring
    For i = 1 To 20
        If (i = 20) Then
            If (leftRing(i) <> leftRing(1)) Then
                colorChangesLeft += 1
            End If
        Else
            If (leftRing(i) <> leftRing(i + 1)) Then
                colorChangesLeft += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Count Color Changes in Right Ring
    For i = 1 To 20
        If (i = 20) Then
            If (rightRing(i) <> rightRing(1)) Then
                colorChangesRight += 1
            End If
        Else
            If (rightRing(i) <> rightRing(i + 1)) Then
                colorChangesRight += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    totalChanges = colorChangesLeft + colorChangesRight
    var = totalChanges
End Sub

 Sub RotateLeftRingClockwise()
    Dim temp As Integer = leftRing(1)
    ' Rotates Rings clockwise direction
    For i = 1 To 20
        If (i = 20) Then
            leftRing(i) = temp
        Else
            leftRing(i) = leftRing(i + 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For this example, I've tried to declare colorChanges as both a global variable and a variable within the Solve_Click sub function.

Comment: Well I'm stuck and thought I'd ask for some help, it isn't like I use this very often. Why bother to criticize me instead of just ignoring my question? I've gone through debugging for the past 4 hours. I'm sorry if this sounds rude, but next time just don't bother writing on a post where you don't like the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, it *will* stay the same.

You basically have a circular buffer of values (due to your special handle when `i = 20`) and you count the number of times the value changes from index to index.

That number is not going to change if you simply rotate the values through the circular buffer.

Take for example, the array `{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}`. There are four transitions there, `1-2`, `2-3`, `3-4` and `4-1`.

If you then rotate the list clockwise, you get `{4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}` and the transitions are `4-1`, `1-2`, `2-3` and `3-4`.

In other words, the *order* of the transitions may change, but the *quantity* does not.

---

Based on your addition of the `RotateLeftRingClockwise` code, this is where your problem lies.

Because it simply rotates the left ring, you're not handling the intersection points of the Hungarian rings correctly. Rotating the left ring would, as well as moving the values around the left ring, *change* two of the array elements in the right ring (and vice versa), as per the diagram below:

```
   array element 1 (in a 32-element array)
          |
      +---+---+
      |       |
      V       V
     LLL     RRR
   LL   LL RR   RR
  L       *       R      <- shared cell is left(29)/right(5)
 L       R L       R
 L       R L       R
L       R   L       R
L       R   L       R
L       R   L       R
 L       R L       R
 L       R L       R
  L       *       R      <- shared cell is left(21)/right(13)
   LL   LL RR   RR
 \   LLL     RRR   /
  \               /
   \----->>>-----/
     Direction of
       increasing
         array index
```

Because your rotate code does *not* do this, the transition count of both rings will remain identical and hence the sum of them will not change.

For example, say the top-middle cells are array element 1 (as shown) and it increases in a anti-clockwise direction (as your code seems to indicate from the fact that a clockwise rotation shifts from `ring[i+1]` to `ring[i]`).

What your code needs to do is first rotate the left ring and then force the new values for the `*` cells into the right ring, something like:

```
Sub RotateLeftRingClockwise()
    Dim temp As Integer = leftRing(1)
    For i = 1 To 19
        leftRing(i) = leftRing(i + 1)
    Next
    leftRing(20) = temp

    rightRing( 5) = leftRing(29)
    rightRing(13) = leftRing(21)
End Sub
```

Those array indexes in the last two lines are specific to my diagram above (32 cells rather than 20), you'll need to adjust them for your own puzzle.

If you make those changes (and similar ones to your other three rotation functions), you should find that the function starts returning different values. Specifically, rotating the left ring will leave the left value unchanged but should change the right value as different balls come into the intersection point.

Comment: well each element in the leftRing and rightRing have 20 elements and each have been randomized with values ranging from 1 through 4. The initial countColorChangesInRings call works perfectly, then when the rotate is done, the countColorChanges function doesn't update the differences in color changes. But when I update the screen, the correct implementation appears in the GUI.

Comment: well the idea is that there are 2 rings, it is the Hungarian Rings puzzle, there are 2 intersection points which will change the sequence of elements slightly (at most 4 color changes per rotation). The value however, stays the same no matter how many times I rotate each ring in either direction.

Comment: So `rotateleftringclockwise` may change the _values_ in the right ring? You need to show us the rotate code as well.

Comment: Added to the bottom of the post

Comment: @James, then my answer stands. Your current rotate-left-ring changes _only_ the order of elements in the left ring. That means the right ring won't change at all and the transition count in the left ring will also remain unchanged. You need to fix your rotate code so that it affects both rings in a hungarian-rings osrt of way.

Comment: But what gets me is that once the rotate is done, you can manually count the color changes and is usually either less or more than the original count (on the screen image). The left and right rings each have 2 rings in common (both the intersections) so their is a slight difference in the rightRing. Does that change your answer or am I wrong in the fact that the rightRing has no barrings on the color changes?

Comment: @James, see the update as to what you need to do. I suspect what you're seeing on screen is simply because of the order you're drawing the rings. The left ring rotation has no code which changes the right ring at the moment - that's what you need to fix.

Comment: The way I have leftRing array is that element 1 is 1 ball to the left of the top intersection, and last element is 1 under to the right of the top intersection. I'm not really seeing where I have coded wrong? If you rotate the left ring, the intersection points can only go from intersection to element 1 in leftRing and the bottom intersection would go from element 16 to 17 (up 1 to right) which it does.

Comment: The intersection _points_ shouldn't move, they will always be at specific indexes - that's because you're moving the actual balls. See the latest update for a solution, all you now need to do is figure out the correct intersection indexes.

Comment: Ah, now I see where I was going wrong. You're a lifesaver! I've been wondering why the number wouldn't change but the image rotations was working perfectly. I appreciate the time you took to help!!!